# How to comment out multiple or all files in a directory?

Tags: files, projectile, comment, directories, script

I frequently use commands like `paredit-comment-dwim`, `comment-dwim`,  and `comment-region`. I am also aware these commands can have a compound effect with the `mark` command.

But, I would like to comment out the content of multiple files in a project. There must be a way to do it in Emacs.

I already use projectile, if it helps.

How can I comment-out the content of multiple files in a project (inside a directory)?

If it makes the process easier, how can I comment-out the content of all files in a project (inside a directory)?

Would you do an Elisp or bash script to do the trick?

obs. (i): Comment-out means to disable a section of source code by converting it into a comment.

obs. (ii): I need this for debugging reasons. Some library is probably screwing up the compilation making it an endless process. I am going to do a binary search on each of them and I need to comment out the other parts.

obs. (iii): the folder is the cornerstone of a Clojure/ClojureScript dynamic web app project.

obs. (iv): in case you are wondering about an [X-Y question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) situation, I need this as a handy sidekick to try solving [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73902586/why-is-shadow-cljs-compile-app-returning-build-complete-but-the-process-keep).

Comment: You want to *edit all the files* such that every line of the file has been commented out, yes?

Comment: Unless we're only talking about a small number of files, I would almost definitely use a shell script for this myself; but the specifics depend greatly on the language and commenting syntax.  It's not safe in all file types to apply comment syntax to every single line.

Comment: Yes, @phils. This is what I want! Sorry if the question was not clear.

Comment: I will updated my question with more details.

Comment: If we *are* talking about a small number of files, I would probably use a keyboard macro in Emacs starting from dired, recording something like: `RET`, `C-x h`, `M-;`, `C-x C-s`, `C-x k RET`, `n`.

Comment: I just wonder if this might be an [X-Y question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/231821). Why do you need/want to comment out all of the *content* of each of the files? Is it just to prevent some action that acts on all files from doing something with those files? If so, would just temporarily removing from the file list (e.g. renaming/moving) do what you really need/want?

Comment: I was willing to start from a fresh slate on the Clojure project.  Everything would be comment out except for the `shadow-cljs.edn` file. Then, I would add dependencies and see if the program compiles, one by one. Despite the fact that the dependencies were added, the functions they have would not be invoked.

Comment: My knee-jerk reaction is to go towards a `find/sed` solution in such cases: you could use bulk-operations in `dired` and its ilk, but I don't have them at the tips of my fingers, so I tend to slide into the (for me) least-resistance path of command line tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some people mentioned it in the comments and it was indeed **not** necessary to comment-out everything for my debugging endeavor.

I just commented-out a file called `app/core.cljs`. This is the "heart of the application", it is a file that glues everything together and starts the application triggering code in other files.